# Xunit Test case is giving an error involving the constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have an interface defined as:

```
    public interface IProfessorsDAL
    {
        Task<(bool, string)> UploadToBlob(string filename, byte[] imageBuffer = null, Stream stream = null);
    }
```

And I have defined the class as:

```
public class ProfessorsMockDAL : IProfessorsDAL
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ProfessorsMockDAL(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
 public static string stConnectionString { get; } = "AppSetting:StaConnectionString";

        public async Task<(bool, string)> UploadToBlob(string filename, byte[] imageBuffer = null, Stream stream = null)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = null;
            string storageConnectionString = _configuration[stConnectionString];

            // Check whether the connection string can be parsed.
            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create the CloudBlobClient that represents the Blob storage endpoint for the storage account.
                    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                    // Create a container called 'uploadblob' and append a GUID value to it to make the name unique. 
                    cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("uploadblob");

                    // Get a reference to the blob address, then upload the file to the blob.
                    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);


                    if (imageBuffer != null)
                    {
                        // OPTION A: use imageBuffer (converted from memory stream)
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(imageBuffer, 0, imageBuffer.Length);
                    }
                    else if (stream != null)
                    {
                        // OPTION B: pass in memory stream directly
                        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (false, null);
                    }

                    return (true, cloudBlockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedStorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString());
                }
                catch (StorageException ex)
                {
                    return (false, null);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return (false, null);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to write a Xunit Test case for the same which is:

```
 public class UnitTest1
    {

        private readonly IProfessorsDAL _professorsDAL;

        public UnitTest1(IProfessorsDAL professorsDAL)
        {
            _professorsDAL = professorsDAL;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task UploadToBlob()
        {
    
            var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
            //Setup mock file using a memory stream
            var content = "Hello World from a Fake File";
            var fileName = "test.pdf";
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            fileMock.Setup(_ => _.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
            fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
            fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);

            var file = fileMock.Object;


            var uploadSuccess = false;
            string uploadedUri = null;
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                (uploadSuccess, uploadedUri) = await _professorsDAL.UploadToBlob(file.FileName, null, stream);
            }


            Assert.True(uploadSuccess);

        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error like this while executing the test case:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IProfessorsDAL professorsDAL

I found out that I need to mock something but I am not sure how. Can anyone put some ideas on how to do it properly?
Also, this logic is correct since I can upload files properly using an endpoint in the controller. I have the connection string in my appsettings.json

Comment: you are injecting an interface into your unit test.  I've never seen that - I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.  Your unit test should instantiate the class you are trying to test.

Comment: So if I try to instantiate the class like `var service = new ProfessorsDAL();` I need to pass the configuration object inside, how do i do that?

Comment: you'd create a mock of it.  I really like the `Moq` framework

Comment: I used the Moq framework to create this : `var configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();` and tried to use the same as parameter to the instantiation but it says: `cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration>' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'` . I am sorry I am new to this

Comment: `var service = new ProfessorsDAL(configuration.Object)`

Comment: Okay now the test is running its going into the uploadblob function but its not able to parse the connection string, it is working though with the endpoint.

Comment: I updated the code with a small change in the class file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using this piece of code instead of injecting an interface to the unittest:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var service = new ProfessorsMockDAL(config);
```

I just instantiated the class with a configuration that is build using appsettings.json in the test project location.